# C - Stack allocation using only ntdll

Tags: c, winapi, stack, allocation, ntdll

Is there an API call or any another similar way, that uses only `ntdll.dll`, to allocate memory on the stack?

I know `alloca()` does that, but I can't use it because I can use only function from `ntdll.dll`.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such function. You can write it yourself easily.

Comment: Stack allocation isn't provided by the OS, it's something that every single user function does in its prologue.  Your compiler should translate `alloca()` into the same instructions found in the prologue, no function call required.  If it doesn't, look at inline assembly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - exist, you wrong.

Comment: @RbMm can you give me a link to the doc

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - no, can not. I use this already many years :) ntdll.dll export `_alloca_probe` (`__chkstk`) - yes of course this is undocumented, but not I ask this question

Comment: @RbMm: `_alloca_probe()` or `__chkstk()` may be used together with allocation on the stack, but it does not do the stack allocation.

Comment: @BenVoigt - no, thay exactly do this task. and what thay do by your version ? I use this functions *many years*

Comment: You will probably get better answers if you explain why you "can only use functions from `ntdll.dll`."  I can think of at least two good reasons why you might need to do that -- but both of them involve doing things that only Microsoft's employees have all the necessary information to do properly, and if you worked at Microsoft you wouldn't be asking this question here.

Comment: @RbMb: They stride through the new allocation, making sure that every page is accessed so that the guard page exception occurs, triggering the OS paging logic to force pages to be committed for this area of the stack if it was formerly only reserved..

Comment: @zwol: Well, I'm pretty sure what he actually meant was "do not use functions except those found in `ntdll.dll`" and that is entirely possible, because `sub esp, NNN` doesn't require any functions at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt - yes, may be and this say - `_alloca` is patially compiler intrinsic which called this function internally

Comment: @BenVoigt It is my understanding that you cannot normally avoid having `kernel32.dll` loaded into your process, so "only ntdll" doesn't actually make any sense as a design constraint.  Unless you're writing CSRSS.EXE or similar - but then you're Microsoft.

Comment: @zwol - may be boot execute app

Comment: @zwol: Ok, but maybe he doesn't want his code to call into `kernel32.dll`.  Perhaps because of address space layout randomization?

Comment: @BenVoigt Why would one care about ASLR, unless they're writing a shellcode or exploit?

Comment: @Mark: Hotpatching is used by defenders as well as attackers.

Comment: @BenVoigt Still doesn't explain the unnecessary fear from ASLR.

Comment: @BenVoigt - about boot execute apps, starting by `smss.exe` like `chkdsk.exe` which can use only `ntdll.dll` you listen ? but this is only my guess

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, that's another possibility.

Comment: use `alloca` in self code ! linker can say you about unresolved external (`_alloca_probe_16` or `__chkstk` ) but you can found this symbols in `alloca16.obj` and `chkstk.obj`which can be found in `VC` subfolder and also in `ntdllp.lib` (but not in `ntdll.lib`)

Comment: @RbMm That is the _other_ possibility (besides subsystem servers) that I was thinking of.  It, too, requires documentation that I was under the impression was not available outside Microsoft.

Comment: @zwol - what is "documented" or "documentation" is very volatile. formal can say use `ntdll.dll` is taboo at all. but by fact it can be use.

Comment: @BenVoigt - and about "actual allocation"  in x86 the `_alloca_probe_16` , `_alloca_probe` and `_chkstk`(last 2 is the same) do the *actual* allocation, not only stack checking, despite they name. but in x64 - only stack checking , when `sub rsp,rax` do compiler (all this is for `CL` compiler) if be absolute exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alloca is partially intrinsic function, implemented by compiler. but internally it call `_alloca_probe_16` (for x86) or `__chkstk`(x64) for move guard page down on stack. implementation of this functions exist in `alloca16.obj` and `chkstk.obj`which can be found in `VC` subfolder (where exacly depended from VC version) - you can add this obj for link process or even first convert it to lib. also in latest WDK libs - exist `ntdllp.lib` (not confuse with `ntdll.lib`) - it also containing all need for implementation ( `ntdll.dll` export `_chkstk` (for x86) and `__chkstk` (for x64))

---

again in more details:

when you write in src code

`alloca(cb)`
`CL` compiler generate in x86

```
mov eax,cb
call _alloca_probe_16 ; do actual stack allocation and probe
```

and in x64 version

```
mov         ecx,eax 
add         rcx,0Fh 
cmp         rcx,rax 
ja          @@0
mov         rcx,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFF0h 
@@0:
and         rcx,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0h 
mov         rax,rcx 
call        __chkstk ; probe only
sub         rsp,rax ; actual stack allocation
```

so `_alloca_probe_16` and/or `__chkstk` must be implemented somewhere or you got link error - unresolved external symbol.

in latest WDK builds exist `ntdllp.lib` (note about `p` - not `ntdll.lib`) which containing this implementation. in this case your PE will be import `__chkstk` or `_alloca_probe` from `ntdll.dll` (this functions exported how minimum from XP - both this functions is point to same code, simply alias)

another solution - in `VC` folders can be found `alloca16.obj` and `chkstk.obj` - you can use this obj as link input (or merge `alloca16.obj` + `chkstk.obj` in single lib file). in this case your PE will be nothing import.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need something architecture dependent because allocation on the stack is (generally) architecture independent.

If you're using C99 you have a standard way of doing this, using Variable Length Arrays: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

You'd quite simply write something like this:

```
char mybuffer[my_size];
```

And it will be allocated on the stack.

Comment: what if `my_size` *unknown* and compile time ? this is *not a solution*

Comment: @RbMm well, VLAs are explicitly designed for that scenario

Comment: @RbMm: That's what makes it a variable-length array.  This IS a solution, if you have a C99 compiler.  Most Windows compilers aren't.

Comment: @RbMM VLA is the definition of "when `my_size` is unknown in compile time"

Comment: if we use windows this also worked ? if I want use CL but not gcc ?

Comment: @RbMm: "Variable length arrays are not currently supported in Visual C++."

Comment: @BenVoigt - but `_alloca` worked in this place. and I know this exactly because very active use in self code. compiler partial internal implement this, but for move guard page calling `__chkstk` or also `_alloca_probe_16` (on x86 only). this function implementation we can got say from obj in VC complect or ntdllp.lib. interesting what is wrong in my answer ?

Comment: also VLA can not be used in loop - for additional space allocation - so this much less functional solution

Comment: I believe this solution will call __chkstk or another C runtime function, so it isn't really any different to using _alloca.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - yes, this really call analog of __chkstk internaly, *but* this can not be used in loop for additional allocations, by syntax limitation, when _alloca - can. I very frequently use this feature in self code

Comment: i mean next template `do { if (cb < rcb) cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);  status = SomeFunc(buf, cb, &rcb); } while(status == <status_buffer_small>);` - how this implement with VLA

Answer (score 1):

Because `alloca` manipulates the stack pointer, it isn't a "real" function, it's a "compiler intrinsic".  If you compile a function that uses `alloca` to assembly language, you *should* see that it is translated directly to `sub esp, NNN` rather than `call alloca`.  (There might be a call to a function *in addition to* the `sub esp, NNN`.  In that case you need to find out what that function does, where it's normally defined, and arrange for your application to provide a substitute.  You're already jumping through all sorts of unusual hoops to use nothing but NTDLL, this is just one more.)

If you *do* see `call alloca` and no `sub esp, NNN`, that is very likely to mean that your compiler has only a fake implementation of `alloca` that is *not* giving you memory allocated from the stack, and you shouldn't use it at all.

Comment: In addition to adjusting the stack pointer, having `alloca` or a VLA used inside the function body forces the compiler to use the long prolog and epilog, e.g. `push ebp; mov ebp, esp; sub esp, NNN` .... `mov esp, ebp; pop ebp` instead of simply `sub esp, NNN` ... `add esp, NNN`

Comment: we need ckeck stack allocation - which `CL` do by call `__chkstk` which already not "compiler intrinsic" - you forget about guard pages in stack

Comment: @zwol - are you using stack allocations in self code, have experience in this ?

Comment: @RbMm Yes. Not specifically in the environment OP is asking about, but a stack is a stack and there's only a few ways `alloca` can be implemented.  I believe this answer is essentially in agreement with yours; I didn't give the name of the function that might be called, because it's totally compiler-dependent what its name is or whether there even _is_ a function call, but I'm thinking of the same thing you are.

Comment: @RbMm if you've never heard of the `alloca` implementation being fake, see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/alloca.c

Comment: i oriented to `CL` - may be i wrong, but faster of all OP used it. simply down stack pointer not a problem, but we need check, move guard page. this is windows os requirements. `CL` call `_alloca_probe_16` (for x86) or `__chkstk` (x64) implementation of this small independent functions can be found in `VC` folder and also in `ntdllp.lib` (native if OP use ntdll) - so i give absolute concrete answer how use this